# Visual Studio (C#) - fix missing references (DLLs)

Tags: .net, dll

I seem to be running into quite a few cases where I want to use a certain class in a certain package, but cannot find it when trying to add a references. (I'm talking about external packages here, for example .Net stuff.)

The most recent example is me wanting to use the .Net Ping class. Not knowing any other way to find out, I'm using the reverse package search here: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

It tells me a need the System.Net.NetworkInformation reference. However, this is nowhere to be found in my VS.

So I try a bit of googling, and it seems that this package SHOULD be available. However, I have a pretty standard Windows 7 64-bit system, with a more or less the typical applications installed. So why don't I have this?

I found a site explaining me how to manually register the System.Net.NetworkInformation.DLL file, but first unregistering it and then registering it again. However, when trying to unregister it, the message from my system is that the specified module couldn't be found.

So, specifically: How do I fix this? And more generally: How to go about finding out why a reference everyone else seems to use without any trouble isn't availbale for me?